# How can I fix error npm run dev in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, npm

I have an error with npm when install in Laravel 6 it's now working  I don't know despite of i did all the steps in order

**this are my versions:**
Laravel version 6
npm 6.13.7
Node 13.5.0

**I did the commends in order**

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
php artisan ui vue --auth 
npm install 
npm run dev
```

**but when do npm run dev it's error show**

> ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js): ModuleBuildError: Module build
>   failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): ValidationError:
>   Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an
>   options object that does not match the API schema.
>    - options has an unknown property 'outputStyle'. These properties are valid:    object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?,
>   sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
>       at validate (D:\project\laravel\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:85:11)
>       at Object.loader (D:\project\laravel\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
>       at D:\project\laravel\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
>       at D:\project\laravel\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
>       at D:\project\laravel\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
>       at runSyncOrAsync (D:\project\laravel\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
>       at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\project\laravel\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
>       at D:\project\laravel\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4
>       at D:\project\laravel\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:85:15
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)  @ ./resources/sass/app.scss
>
> ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
>   (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>   ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been
>   initialized using an options object that does not match the API
>   schema.
>    - options has an unknown property 'outputStyle'. These properties are valid:    object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?,
>   sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
>       at validate (D:\project\laravel\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:85:11)
>       at Object.loader (D:\project\laravel\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)  @
>   ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   errno 2 npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development
>   node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules
>   --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-22T21_12_44_218Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run
>   development` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @
>   dev script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-22T21_12_44_441Z-debug.log

**and this my package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "webpack": "^4.41.6"
    }
}
```

**Thanks**

Comment: You can try downgrading sass-loader versiion to 7.1.0 `npm uninstall --save-dev sass-loader
npm install --save-dev sass-loader@7.1.0`

Comment: thankyou it's working good after downgrading sass-loader versiion to 7.1.0

Answer (score 29):

Had same error, solved by [reinstalling `sass-loader` v7.1](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2206#issuecomment-527730992)

```
npm uninstall --save-dev sass-loader
npm install --save-dev sass-loader@7.1.0
```